# Convert .suit to .ttf

Tags: windows, mac, fonts, file-format

Is there a way to convert a Mac .suit font file to a Windows .ttf file (or some other Windows accessible file)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Free online font converter

http://onlinefontconverter.com/

Comment: a website that doesn't actually let you use it, because it thinks the latest version of internet explorer is NaN, and Chrome is a beta version. Sigh.

Comment: Well, the site opens OK in Edge and Firefox, but unfortunately the conversion fails for .suit files.